# Stomp protocol history and owner

Tags: stomp

I am benchmarking messaging middleware and protocols.
I wanted to write a summary about each protocol I am testing.  I found no information about STOMP, except for license.  the official website is extremely sparse, the wikipedia term is a stub, and online search also brough up nothing.

Who owns and maintains the protocol? 
Who publishes the specs?
nice-to-have would be some historical facts about the evolution of the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read through the official STOMP [website](http://stomp.github.com/index.html) ?

The Spec are located on the site, [v1.0](http://stomp.github.com/stomp-specification-1.2.html), [v1.1](http://stomp.github.com/stomp-specification-1.2.html) and [v1.2](http://stomp.github.com/stomp-specification-1.2.html) (latest)

Releases are done via a vote taken on the mailing list, which is listed on the site, you can go there to view the archive and also ask questions.

Comment: yes, of course I went to the official site. where in the site does it mention anything about the history of this protocol? so the mailing list is the owner of the protocol? usually there is a group that consists of several corporate bodies which governs the evolution of the standard (as is the case with AMQP)

Comment: If you look at each spec you will see a changelog from previous, that's about all the documented history there is.  The SPEC is open and anyone can submit change requests which will get voted on / discussed on the mailing list.

Comment: ok, I understand that and I marked your answer as accepted. However, changelog is NOT historical notes.  *someone* had to come up with the idea in the first place and that someone had to be known in the industry for the idea to catch up and all the brokers to be written and so on... I can only guess that the protocol was invented in FuseSource? or perhaps Apache...

Answer (score 1):

The following link might help:

http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpreviousversions.action?pageId=30757

Codehaus was the original home of the spec.  Initiated back in 2005 I believe